ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from partially initialized module 'application' (most likely due to a circular import)
I think I have a circular import between the main.py and init.py when initializing the app, but I can't figure out how to properly set it.
Any help would be appreciated. I included some pictures about the project.
Error: While importing 'main', an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):    File "/Users/x/Sites/learning/python/flask/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py",line 218, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)   

File "/Users/x/Sites/learning/python/flask/main.py", line 1, in <module> from application import app   File "/Users/x/Sites/learning/python/flask/application/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from application import routes   

File "/Users/x/Sites/learning/python/flask/application/routes.py", line 1, in <module>
    from application import app, db 

ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from partially initialized module 'application' **(most likely due to a circular import)** (/Users/x/Sites/learning/python/flask/application/__init__.py)

Here is some screenshots of the project:

Packages installed:

main.py
from application import app

init.py
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine
from application import routes

db = MongoEngine()
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db.init_app(app)

Routes.py
from application import app, db
from flask import render_template, request, Response, json

courseData = [
        {"courseID": "1111", "title": "PHP 111", "description": "Intro to PHP", "credits": "3", "term": "Fall, Spring"},
        {"courseID": "2222", "title": "Java 1", "description": "Intro to Java Programming", "credits": "4","term": "Spring"},
        {"courseID": "3333", "title": "Adv PHP 201", "description": "Advanced PHP Programming", "credits": "3", "term": "Fall"},
        {"courseID": "4444", "title": "Angular 1", "description": "Intro to Angular", "credits": "3","term": "Fall, Spring"},
        {"courseID": "5555", "title": "Java 2", "description": "Advanced Java Programming", "credits": "4","term": "Fall"}]

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/index")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", index=True)

@app.route("/login")
def login():
    return render_template("login.html", login=True)

@app.route("/enrollment", methods=["GET","POST"])
def enrollment():
    id = request.form.get('courseID')
    title = request.form['title']
    term = request.form.get('term')
    return render_template("enrollment.html", enrollment=True, data={"id":id,"title":title,"term":term})

@app.route("/courses")
@app.route("/courses/<term>")
def courses(term="2024"):
    return render_template("courses.html", courseData=courseData, courses=True, term=term)

@app.route("/register")
def register():
    return render_template("register.html", register=True)

@app.route("/api/")
@app.route("/api/<idx>")
def api(idx=None):
    if idx is None:
        jdata = courseData
    else:
        jdata = courseData[int(idx)]
    return Response(json.dumps(jdata), mimetype="application/json")

class User(db.Document):
    user_id = db.IntField(unique=True)
    first_name = db.StringField(max_length=50)
    last_name = db.StringField(max_length=50)
    email = db.StringField(max_length=30)
    password = db.StringField(max_length=30)

@app.route("/user")
def user():
    User(user_id=1, first_name="x", last_name="x", email="x@aol.com", password="pass").save()
    User(user_id=2, first_name="Sam", last_name="x", email="xx@aol.com", password="pass").save()
    users = User.objects.all()
    return render_template("user.html", users=users)


The error message alrady tells you what you need to do -- resolve the circular import. __init__.py imports routes and routes imports from __init__.py. What do you need from application import routes for? Deleting it should solve the problem.
